# DELETE entry that is older than current datetime in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-delete

I have tried the following among various other statements but thought one of these should obviously work but no luck so far. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Not getting an error, it's just not working.

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE from < NOW()`
`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE from < '2022-04-16 08:00:00'`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cK4.png)

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Try `quoting` your column name with backticks -- eg DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ``from`` < '2022-04-16 08:00:00'

Comment: is  your "from" column has a datatype of DateTime

Comment: Yes, from column has a data type of DateTime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't name your columns (or other database objects) using reserved SQL keywords such as `FROM`.  That being said, both of your queries are valid once we escape the `from` column:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE `from` < NOW();
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE `from` < '2022-04-16 08:00:00';
```

Comment: I think SQL will be able to "get it", that second from is not a keyword. OR it would have given an error?

Comment: `FROM` is not just a keyword, but a *reserved* keyword.

Comment: @AkashVarde For certain, the OP's query will not run without error.  There could be other problems as well though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleise backticks did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You have done many problems here.
First of all 'from' is a reserved keyword. So please change the word into something to avoid future problems.
And please convert those into timestamp. What you are doing is comparing it with a string eg.'2022-04-16 08:00:00' .  And you have to know what `NOW()` is returning. If you convert everything in timestamp you will get an integer to compare with. Or use date related functions.
Another thing what is the data type of this column?

Comment: It's really not difficult to know what NOW() will return.

Answer (score 1):

As `from` is a reserved word you have to escape its name. Or better change the column-name to something that is not a reserved keyword.

Within MySQL you can do with backticks or (if you MySQL-server is running in ANSI-mode - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) with double-quotes

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE `from` < NOW();
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE "from" < NOW();
```

The double-quotes are also working with PostgreSQL (so it is more standard-SQL) whereas the backticks are only used with MySQL.